# How to convert 1 1/2 inch drain pipe to 2 inches coming from my basement floor?

Tags: drain

I need to have washer and laundry sink installed in my basement. Washer drain needs to be 2". I have only 1 1/2" pipe. Do I need to replace that cleanup box? Lokks like all this is glued together. I'm wondering if there is a way to keep existing cleanup box. I do want to do everything by code. See the image.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the size of the Floor Cleanout is 2"? In the picture it appears that it may be more like 3".

Comment: Yes, the cleanout box have opening about 3" or 4" and has transitional piece from 3" or 4" to 1 1/2. It looks like all that is glued together,,,

Answer (score 1):

If in your picture, the clean-out has a 1.5" to 3" adapter on top, which is glued to the clean-out and the 1.5" above, you will need to replace the clean out. It looks to be 4" bottom, 3" top. Ideally cut about 1" above the bottom of the clean-out, and cut vertical grooves into the remaining clean out and remove the last 1" with pliers. Hopefully if you do that you won't loose any 4" pipe, as you don't have much exposed. May need to sand/clean up the pipe for the new fitting. Then put in a new 3" to 4" clean out. Then you can put a 2" to 3" adapter in, and replace and necessary Ts and piping above to 2".

Answer (score 0):

They make ABS pipe adapters that go from 1 1/2" size to 2" size. They do take up  some vertical space so that TEE that you now have just above the 2" piece will have to be moved up to higher position.

Here is an example of one type of adapter:

[image]

<sup>*(Picture source from [Home Depot Web Page](https://www.homedepot.com/p/2-in-x-1-1-2-in-ABS-DWV-SPG-x-Hub-Flush-Bushing-C58012FHD2112/100342353))*</sup>

Comment: Will that be allowed by code? I'm under impression that drain pipe can only transition from smaller diameter to bigger.

Comment: @DmitriD - The adapter shown is designed to glue onto the end of a 1 1/2" pipe and then the resulting end placed into a place a 2" pipe would normally it. I do not see how that in any way creates a situation where the transition from your 1 1/2" drain line gets smaller on its way to the larger size on the cleanout box. If the size on the top of the cleanout box is currently 3" then you may need an additional 2" to 3" adapter similar to what I have shown above.

Comment: @Michael, I think the 1 1/2" in the picture is already glued into the cleanout fitting. He wants to remove the 1 1/2" and replace it with 2".

Comment: @PlatinumGoose - I now see what you mean. I missed that they want to add a new 2" pipe to the mix. In that case the OP is going to have to replace the cleanout box with something different.